# Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/),which process should I kill?

Tags: 16.04, apt

When I try to upgrade

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Then I have used grep to see all the activity

```
ps aux | grep apt
root      3479  1.1  1.2 288624 102116 ?       SNl  09:29   0:02 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd
_apt     31744  0.0  0.0  47116  5792 ?        SN   09:32   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     31745  0.0  0.0  47116  5708 ?        SN   09:32   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     31746  1.3  0.4 217216 33604 ?        SN   09:32   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
_apt     31747  0.0  0.0  47116  5596 ?        SN   09:32   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     31748  0.0  0.0  47116  5820 ?        SN   09:32   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     31750  0.0  0.0  42708  5032 ?        SN   09:32   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/file
_apt     31751  0.0  0.0  47116  5904 ?        SN   09:32   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     31752  0.0  0.0  47116  5596 ?        SN   09:32   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     31753  0.0  0.0  47116  5600 ?        SN   09:32   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
_apt     31754  0.0  0.0  47116  5884 ?        SN   09:32   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
root     31755  0.0  0.0  34268  4764 ?        SN   09:32   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/cdrom
_apt     31758  0.0  0.0  42832  5544 ?        SN   09:32   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/copy
_apt     31760  0.0  0.0  42740  5480 ?        SN   09:32   0:00 /usr/lib/apt/methods/gpgv
milenko  32362  0.0  0.0  14228  1020 pts/17   S+   09:32   0:00 grep --color=auto apt
```

Which process should I kill?

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/a/878982/158442

Comment: delete those lock files, sudo rm -rf  /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Comment: **Consider** killing the process provided by `sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock`. Read `man lsof`.